# Unable to browse URL with '#', '@' character in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am unable to browse Url that contain `'#'`, `'@'` character.
Before that I am facing problem with `'+'` character but it was resolved when I set
`allowDoubleEscaping` property to true in `requestfiltering`.

I did a little search on google and found that there is this [HotFix](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=614) from microsoft that might fix this issue, still I am not sure and I need help. Thanks in advance.